# How to modify a NSMutableArray element that belongs to the source View Controller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

We are trying to update a TableView, that uses a NSMutableArray as data source.
We got 3 View Controllers: Weeks > Week > Day

App flow is simple:

1. Week List
2. Week detail, with list of Days
3. Day detail

[**view app flow diagram**](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/HartasCuerdas/pnpprj/master/mockups/app-flow-1.png)

In (2) **Week**ViewController.h, we declare daysArray

```
// file: WeekViewController.h
@interface WeekViewController : UIViewController
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *firstDayLabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *daysArray;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *daysTableView;
@end
```

In (3) **Day**ViewController, we use **viewWillDisappear** method that updates the Day in daysArray that belongs to source View Controller

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
  // currentVCIndex is the index of the parent view controller: WeekViewController
  int currentVCIndex = [self.navigationController.viewControllers indexOfObject:self.navigationController.topViewController];
  // parent is the reference to the parent view controller: WeekViewController
  WeekViewController *parent = (WeekViewController *)[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:currentVCIndex];
  // indexPath is a reference to the Cell (in a TableView) that made the Segue to DayViewController
  NSIndexPath *indexPath = [parent.daysTableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
  // ### UPDATES simple UILabel on WeekViewController ###
  parent.firstDayLabel.text = @"new text'";
  // ### UPDATES the DAY OBJECT in an array on WeekViewController ###
  [parent.daysArray replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:self.dayDetail];
  [parent.daysTableView reloadData];
}
```

This last one throws an error: **Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException'**

```
reason:
'-[__NSCFArray replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject:]: mutating method sent to immutable object
```

But if we only include

```
parent.firstDayLabel.text = @"new text'";
```

The label on WeekController is modified correctly.

So, we don't know why we can't replace the object at index of that NSMutableArray object.

We have tried with auxiliary object and mutableCopy, and fail again.

---

UPDATE

Thanks @sapi,

We solved this in previous parts of the code, by replacing

```
self.daysArray = responseObject;
```

with this

```
self.daysArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:responseObject];
```

Comment: Clearly `daysArray` is not a mutable array.  The pointer type does not determine the object type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `daysArray` property on `parent` has most likely been initialised from an immutable array, although it is difficult to tell for sure from the code that you have posted.

You need to remember that if you do something like this:

```
self.daysArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"Hi", @"Bye", nil];
```

then the array you just created will be immutable, notwithstanding that `daysArray` is of type `NSMutableArray`.

I suggest you check the code where you actually give a value to `daysArray`, and make sure that you are actually giving it a mutable object.

---

If this is in fact the problem, it's easy enough to fix.  Following on from the example above, you can do:

```
self.daysArray = [[NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"Hi", @"Bye", nil] mutableCopy];
```

or, alternatively:

```
self.daysArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"Hi", @"Bye", nil]];
```

(Both of those are obviously incredibly contrived for this example.)